# Handling Jquery Promise on AJAX call that returns data

Tags: ajax, jquery-deferred

Hoping for an example of data handling on a jQuery AJAX call.  My AJAX calls run php code that returns -1 if unsuccessful.  I have to date ignored the return promise of the ajax code and, instead, created and returned a new deferred object that is resolved or failed based upon the return data....  for some reason I suspect there is a way to achieve this with less overhead.  Current sample is:

```
   send_Data = function(send_data) {
      var dfd = $.Deferred();
      $.post(sendData.php", send_data), function(data) {
      })
      .success(function(data) {if(data==-1) dfd.fail();
                              } else {dfd.resolve(data);}
      .error(function(e){log_error()})
      return  dfd.promise();
   }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You've made a few mistakes in the example that you provided. This is my 2 cents of help

```
 myAjax = {
 ,dfd = $.Deferred();
,ajax: function () { $.ajax({
                             url: 'connectorURL'
                            ,type: "POST"
                            ,data: {
                                    ExpectedVariable: YouRDataVariable,                 
                            }
                            ,success: function(data){
                            if(data == '-1') {
                                this.dfd.fail();
                                } else {
                                this.dfd.resolve(data);
                                }
                            ,error: function(){
                            console.log('connector error',arguments);
                                }
                        });
                    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    myAjax.ajax();                         
});
```